# Tabs like vim configuration

Tags: tabs

I'd like to know how to set emacs up to do the equivalent of what `vim` does when I have this configuration:

```
cat $HOME/.vimrc 
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

So basically, whenever I hit tab tab to the next tabstop with tabstops set to every 4 spaces.  And use spaces instead of tabs when I type the `tab` key.

### Searching for answer

I did some searches and came up with this:

- [Emacs: indentation takes 4 spaces instead of 2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45058/emacs-indentation-takes-4-spaces-instead-of-2)
- And [this SO answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/66384/16958) which says I can't do this in emacs for every file.  Instead each mode must be set.

So if that is the case, I'm mainly interested in `shell-script[sh]`  mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of `shell-script-mode`, to set the "indentation size" the variable you're looking for is `sh-basic-offset`. From `C-h v sh-basic-offset`:

```
sh-basic-offset is a variable defined in ‘sh-script.el’.

Its value is 4

The default indentation increment.
This value is used for the ‘+’ and ‘-’ symbols in an indentation variable.

  This variable has an alias: ‘sh-indentation’.
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘integerp’.
  You can customize this variable.

[back]
```

The variable for "indentation uses spaces" is `indent-tabs-mode`, which is more of a "global" setting. From `C-h v indent-tabs-mode`:

```
indent-tabs-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Its value is nil

Indentation can insert tabs if this is non-nil.

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘booleanp’.
  You can customize this variable.
  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 18.

[back]
```

If you're familiar with Vim's [modeline magic](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Modeline_magic), Emacs has a similar facility via [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html). For instance, one could add the following to the beginning of a shell script to configure "sh mode" for both Vim and Emacs.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# -*- mode: shell-script; sh-shell: sh; sh-basic-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*-
# vim: set ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 et ft=sh:
```